# Do I have to preproces new data again to predict the model?

Tags: python

I have a save model and I want to load the model for new data predictions. I have new data and I have predicted the model, but the result of the prediction is completely wrong. Do I have to preproces new data again to predict the model?

**This my save model code:**

```
  import numpy as np
  from numpy import loadtxt
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import pandas as pd


  dataset = pd.read_csv('Data_Sensor.csv')
  dataset.head()

  X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:3].values
  y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values


  from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
  from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

  labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
  y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)


  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

  from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
  sc = StandardScaler()
  X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
  X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


  from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

  model = Sequential
  model.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 2))
  model.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

  model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

  model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
  model.save('model.h5')

  y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
  print(y_pred)


  y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
  print(y_pred)  

  from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
  cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

**and this is my load model for predict new data, but the results wrong:**

```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  import sklearn
  from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

  model = load_model('model.h5')
  import pandas as pd

  dataset = pd.read_csv('Data_Sensor.csv')

  dataset.head()


 X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:3].values
 print(X)

 model.predict(X)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, new data must be pre-processed before prediction exactly as you did with the training data.

For your example, you need to retain the fitted `StandardScaler`, e.g. by using `get_params` and `set_params` to restore it.

As suggested in the comments below, a better way of doing this with Keras is to add a [`BatchNormalization`](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/) layer at the beginning of the model. This does the same transformation as the standard scaler and is saved together with the rest of the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 2))
model.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Some models have a regularization layer that does it for you.

Comment: I know but if the OP is already going to retrain than we could simply add `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization`.

Comment: @Yonlif that is a valid suggestion for the OP, perhaps add it as a comment to the question :)

Comment: @Yonlif or let me just add it to my answer